# Nominalization and conjugated form

Tags: particle-の, nominalization, particle-こと

As far as I understood, the nominalization is made with the neutral form of the verb followed by の or こと, as in the example

> 私は読むことが好きです。I like to read.

Though, I found this example where the verb is conjugated.

> この本は、読んだことがありますか ? Have you ever read this book?

How is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> この本は、読んだことがありますか ?

You're right that that is how nominalisation works. Whether you would call it nominalisation in this example is, I think, debatable.

...ことがある is a set phrase which means "there are times when..." / "there is a time when". So when you convert it to the question form you get "are there times when... " / "is there a time when ... " which more naturally becomes "have you ever ...".

I say it's a set phrase but you can analyse it quite simply. こと is a word with many meanings. If we pick 'occasion' as the translation in this case then we get the relative clause 読んだこと meaning "occasion when you read". I'm sure you already know that Xがありますか means "is there X", so you can quie naturally understand the whole sentence as "is there in occasion when you read this book", i.e. "have you ever read this book".

Comment: So in fact my example (この本は、読んだことがありますか ? Have you ever read this book?) is not a typical example of nominalization

Comment: From a strict grammar point of view I'm not sure whether it counts as nominalisation or not. I would certainly say that it isn;t a typical example of nominalisation.

Comment: Regarding your first sentence, please see this link: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/58653/7944

Answer (score 0):

> **こと**  is  basically  a  lexical  noun  ‘thing/fact’,  which  is
> also  used  as  a  nominalizer. Like **の**, it is preceded and followed
> by the forms that precede  and follow nouns.

> In Japanese, no distinction can be made between noun modification and
> relative  clauses

Japanese. A Comprehensive Grammar [2nd ed.]-Routledge (2013)